# How can I specify serialisation with GSON?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

EDIT: Solved, will mark my answer when SO lets me :)

I'm using greenDAO to generate a bunch of classes, and it when I try to get GSON to serialise them, it seems to attempt to serialise some of the fields generated by greenDAO (Which are of no interest to me) and crashes. The object I wish to serialise references other generated objects and lists of generated objects.

GSON says it allows serialisation described by toString() methods, I tried different approaches, but when I examine the output to a file it just appears as the toString() method. Could somebody show me how you could produce a JSON object from a toString() method, or suggest another way to do a custom serialisation.

My Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out in the end :) Turns out I needed to implement a JsonSerializer for each of my objects and specify the serialisation manually. Very tedious! References to other objects require nesting, which I did by using the `toJsonTree()` method. Here's my most readable serializer

```
private class InfoSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Info>
{
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Info src, Type typeOfSrc,
            JsonSerializationContext context)
    {
         JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
         obj.addProperty("details", src.getDetails());
         obj.addProperty("hostId", src.getHostId());
         obj.addProperty("dateCreated", src.getDateCreated().toString());
         obj.addProperty("expiryDate", src.getExpiryDate().toString());
         obj.add("alternativeInfo", getGsonInstance().toJsonTree(src.getAlternativeInfo()));
         obj.add("alternativeTimes", getGsonInstance().toJsonTree(src.getAlternativeTimes()));
         return obj;
    }   
}
```

Note: `getGsonInstance()` is a method I wrote to return a singleton Gson Object.

And it is called by:

```
public String infoToJson(Info i)
{
    GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
    gson.registerTypeAdapter(Info.class, new InfoSerializer());
    return gson.create().toJson(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to avoid serializing certain fields, remember that you can label them with the `transient` keyword. This means they will not be serialized by Gson.

Comment: The problem is that if (and probably when) I regenerate the greenDao objects I would have to manually re-label a good 100 fields as transient.

Comment: Ah, bummer. I'm a bit surprised a DAO lib would lack support for transient fields.

Comment: The main problem is it generates a lot of fields which are used for it's own database mappings and the internal functions, which I can't edit before the classes are generated.

Comment: I see. I appreciate the info. (I'm currently keeping my eye on Java ORM for SQLite, so this is helpful!)

Comment: GreenDAO 1.3.7 label orm specific fields with transient.